# Different database instance in Kohana App and Module

Tags: kohana

I need to make an integration for my application with Wordpress. I have a module for that. But I need to use different database instances. In my App I use 'default' and in Wordpress module I want to use 'wordpress' database instance. How can I do that? Because Database::$default = 'wordpress' in modules\wordpress\init.php sets instances for Module and App.

Comment: You can assign specific database groups to a model using the `$_db_group` property. Use it in a base model in your module and extend from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined two database connections in your configuration files like this:

**`config/database.php`** (can be in `APPPATH`, `MODPATH`, etc.)

```
return array
(
    'default' => array
    (
        'type'       => 'mysql',
        'connection' => array(
            'hostname'   => 'localhost',
            'username'   => 'dbuser',
            'password'   => 'mypassword',
            'persistent' => FALSE,
            'database'   => 'my_db_name',
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
    ),
    'wordpress' => array(
        'type'       => 'mysql',
        'connection' => array(
            'hostname'   => 'localhost',
            'username'   => 'other_user',
            'password'   => 'mypassword',
            'persistent' => FALSE,
            'database'   => 'wordpress',
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
    ),
);
```

then you can refer to them like this:

```
// This would connect to the database defined as 'default'
$default = Database::instance();

// This would connect to the database defined as 'wordpress'
$remote  = Database::instance('wordpress');
```

If you are using the `ORM` module, you do it like this in each `Model` that uses the WordPress database:

```
protected String $_db_group = 'wordpress';
```

(Or, you can create an abstract class...

```
abstract class Model_WordPress extends ORM
{
    protected String $_db_group = 'wordpress';
}
```

...and then have your WordPress `Model`s extend `Model_WordPress` instead of directly from `ORM`.  For example, `class Model_WordPress_Post extends Model_WordPress ...`.)